# Show that the set $D=\{y\in \Bbb R^n:\exists x\in C $ such that $||x-y||=r\}$ is closed

Tags: general-topology, proof-verification, metric-spaces

> Let $C$ be a closed subset of $\Bbb R^n$ and $r>0$ be a real number.Show that the set $D=\{y\in \Bbb R^n:\exists x\in C $ such that $||x-y||=r\}$ is closed in $\Bbb R^n$.

Let $y_n$ be a sequence in $D$ such that $y_n\to y.$
Then for each $n\exists x_n $ such that $||y_n-x_n||=r$.

Now $||x_n||=||x_n-y_n+y_n||\le r+||y_n||\to r+y$.

So $x_n\to a\in C$.

I am stuck here.How to show $y\in D$ from here.

Comment: I don't see how you get "so $x_n\to a$". However, once you've got $x_n\to a\in C,$ doesn't it follow by continuity that $||y_n-x_n||\to||y-a||?$ So $||y-a||=r?$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot: $x_n \in C$.

$||x_n||=||x_n-y_n+y_n||\le r+||y_n||\to r+y$ is not correct. Correct is:

$||x_n||=||x_n-y_n+y_n||\le r+||y_n||\to r+||y||$.

From here you can not deduce that $(x_n)$ is convergent ! You can deduce: $(x_n)$ is bounded, since $(y_n)$ is bounded.

Hence $(x_n)$ contains a convergent subseqence $(x_{n_k})$. Let $a$ be the limit of this subsequence. Since $C$ is closed: $a \in C$.

Furthermore we have: $||y_{n_k}-x_{n_k}||=r$ for all $k$. With $ k \to \infty$ we get

$$||y-a||=r.$$

This shows $y \in D$.

Answer (score 1):

You need to state that each $x_n\in C$. If you could prove that
$(x_n)$ converges, it then converges to a point $x\in C$ and
then $\|x-y\|=r$, as you need.

Alas, the sequence $(x_n)$ need not converge, but it is a bounded sequence
(why?) so has a convergent subsequence, and that is good enough.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: an altrrnative approach is using the **topological** concept of closedness. Indeed the distance function is continuous and your set is nothing but the pre-image of a point (which is closed) plus some intersection. From these info the conclusion is immediate

Comment: It would be if x were a constant.  As x ranges over C, why does that method work?